# Getting "Received too large SFTP packet" when logging in with Root using WinSCP to Google Compute Engine virtual machine instance

Tags: ssh, root, sftp, winscp

Hi I can login to the GCE VM with WinSCP using my own username, cannot login as root...this is by default according to Google, and can be changed.

Changed like this:

Step 1: Login SSH and Su Root

```
# sudo su root
```

Step 2: Change password Root

```
#passwd root
```

Step 3: Config SSHD allow Root login

```
#nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
PermitRootLogin yes
PasswordAuthentication yes

#service sshd restart (I used ssh as I'm using ubuntu and sshd wouldn't work)
```

Tried to login as root via WinSCP but I get

> "Received too large (1349281121 B) SFTP packet. Max supported packet
>   size is 1024000 B.  The error is typically caused by message printed
>   from startup script (like .profile). The message may start with
>   'Plea'." Cannot initialize SFTP protocol. Is the host running a SFTP
>   server?"

Any ideas?

Comment: Got the error when trying to log on to a newly created AWS EC2 instance. The solution was to use the `admin` username instead of `root`. The *Plea* thing turned out to be a message asking `Please login as the user "admin" rather than the user "root"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm, I added this in WinSCP in advanced settings under "protocol options":
sudo /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-servers

I can login with my own username and move files now. Although not exactly sure how this works, I think it somehow changes you to root user at login?

More info: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_su

Comment: This works for Ubuntu 18.04 as well, just has to drop last 's': sudo /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server not '..servers'

Answer (score 20):

**Received too large SFTP packet. Max supported packet size is 102400 B**

**Cause:**
This problem can arise when your **.bashrc** file is printing data to the screen (e.g.[archey](https://github.com/djmelik/archey), [screenfetch](https://github.com/KittyKatt/screenFetch)). The **.bashrc** file runs every time any console shell is initialized.

[image]

**Solution:**
Simply move any scripts that generate output from your **.bashrc** file to your **.bash_profile**. The **.bash_profile** only runs when you create a physical shell session.

Comment: You're right; note that any 'echo' command in your profile may cause the problem. To resolve this, comment any kind of 'echo' in your .bashrc file and reconnect the session.

Comment: i fall back to SCP, why shouldn't WinSCP just ignore that printing, hard to dig it out from .bashrc /etc/bashrc /etc/profile, etc. many of them

Comment: Thank you so much. I added an `echo` statement to my `.bashrc` and it prevented Transmit for Mac from connecting to my Amazon Linux EC2 instance. In case anybody runs into the same issue I had. (Error simply was "Can't connect")

Answer (score 14):

NOTE: Just for anyone who comes across this and simply wants to copy files and doesn't matter what file protocol they use. You can just switch file protocol from SFTP to SCP to avoid this issue. Thought it might be worth a mention.

Comment: tks, using SCP works, but im still receiving the error and my .bashrc /etc/bashrc... are not printing out anything

Answer (score 4):

If you used Ubuntu linux and try to connect the server then "Please login as the Ubuntu user" you should sftp as the ubuntu user, not as root.

Try that, hope it will work for you!

Thanks!

Comment: Same problem when switching from CentOS 6 to 7, it used to work with root, but not anymore. SSH attempt with root responsed with

`Please login as the user "centos" rather than the user "root".` Changing user in WinSCP solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Disbale Ubuntu Welcome message for any user logged via SSH:

```
sudo chmod -x /etc/update-motd.d/*
```

Secondly, you'll be facing `Error Code 1` that is to be solved by creating **somefile** (without ~ and . in its name) in dir **/etc/sudoers.d/** with a line:

```
user1 ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/su -c /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

Granting **user1** a permission to connect to server via SFTP as SuperUser without promting for sudo password.
Of course, don't forget to run `sudo systemctl restart sshd` afterwards.

After that in advanced connection settings of WinSCP you can specify in SFTP tab:

```
sudo su -c /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

So you'll be able to write to protected files/folders.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you can login with the user ie to check this run

```
cat /ect/passwd
```

the user should not have :/sbin/nologin

Answer (score 0):

See WinSCP article on [Received too large (... B) SFTP packet. Max supported packet size is 102400 B](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/message_large_packet)

> If … (from the subject [error message]) is a very large number then the problem is typically caused by a message printed from some profile/logon script. It violates an SFTP protocol. Some of these scripts are executed even for non-interactive (no TTY) sessions, so they cannot print anything (nor ask user to type something).

Comment: I didn't try this as adding "sudo /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-servers" in WinSCP advanced setting worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @ThatOneCoder's answer on the cause being too much output from .bashrc: in e.g. Ubuntu, there is also the system wide **/etc/bash.bashrc** that might be "too wordy" and cause the *Received too large SFTP packet* error.

It's a "system wide .bashrc", and if you want to execute code for all logging in, that's one location to place it. If you nixed ~/.bashrc and still get the error, check the contents of **/etc/bash.bashrc**.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you haven't given shell access permission to the user.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Actually this answer give me a good hint!

Answer (score -2):

I faced the same issue trying to login on my ubuntu 16.04 EC2 server as "root" via WinSCP. I spent a lot of time trying to fix it but in the end a simple workaround worked for me.

I ssh into the instance using PuTTY with the username "ubuntu". After this I typed

```
sudo -i
```

and with this the user was changed to root.